# Drupal 8, how fix the error 'class not found' for custom class ?

Tags: 8

Its a php issue but maybe I missing a 'Drupal 8' thing ?

I have this custom module :

```
> mymodule (directory)
    > mymodule.module
    > src (directory)
        > myclass.php
        > myclassinterface.php
```

In myclass.php, I have :

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\src;

Class myclass implements myclassinterface{
    ...
}
```

In my mymodule.module, I have :

```
use Drupal\mymodule\src\myclass;
...
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
    $test = new myclass();
    // or $test = new Drupal\mymodule\src\myclass(); // same error, class not found
}
```

And when I load a page via my browser, I get a blank page and apache log tell me the class 'Drupal\mymodule\src\myclass' not found.

I don't understand..where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the "src" from your namespace and use statements. Wipe the cache after making that change.

Comment: remove src is the solution, thanks =) can you explan why the "src" cause issue ?

Comment: The autoloader looks in the src folder, so there is no need to specify it.

Comment: Here is a link on how it works https://www.drupal.org/node/2156625